# How to find the inverse Fourier Transform of the product of two bessel functions of the first kind and a complex exponential function?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, special-functions

I am attempting to find a closed form or symbolic expression of the inverse Fourier transform of the product of two Bessel functions of the first kind and a complex exponential, e.g.

$P(t) = IFT_w \{ F(w)\}  = \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {J_0 (aw)J_0 (bw)e^{ - jcw} e^{jwt} dw}$

where $a, b, c$ are real values and $0<a, b, c<1$.

I've been tried so hard to solve it and recently found some clue in the textbook, Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, 7th ed. witten by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik:

$\int_0^\infty  {e^{ - ax} J_v (\beta x)J_v (\gamma x)} dx = \frac{1}{{\pi \sqrt {\gamma \beta } }}Q_{v - \frac{1}{2}} \left( {\frac{{\alpha ^2  + \beta ^2  + \gamma ^2 }}{{2\beta \gamma }}} \right)$ , where $Q_{v}$ is Legendre function of the second kind,and the equality holds only if

${\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} \{ \alpha  \pm i\beta  \pm i\gamma \}  > 0,{\rm  }\gamma  > 0,{\rm  }{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} \{ v\}  >  - \frac{1}{2}$.

Since the complex exponential term in $P(t)$ becomes $e^{-jw(c - t)}$; thus, $\alpha=j(c-t)$, and we also have $\beta=a$, $\gamma=b$, which are all reals, $P(t)$ does not satisfy ${\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} \{ \alpha  \pm i\beta  \pm i\gamma \}  > 0$, so I couldn't use the result.

I've tried to get $P(t)$ with Mathematica, but it has returned with nothing. Today, I tried to solve it using the convolution theorem, but the result is somewhat very long and messy; the direct solving of the integral seems a nightmare for me.

Does anyone knows how to solve the integral or a closed form expression of $P(t)$?
Any little clue will be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you still need the answer? I think I computed something similar a while ago using convolution. If I am not wrong the result is compactly supported with logarithmic singularities somewhere.